# Hudson hangs on "Started by user anonymous"

Tags: git, jenkins, hudson, freeze

My hudson job just started hanging at the start of the build, output looks like:
Started by user anonymous
[spinner]

It can be in this state for several hours, I don't know what can be wrong. Any ideas? How I can debug this stuff?

Comment: Provoke a stack trace and see where it spends it time.

Comment: kill -3 on the process and you will have a thread dump. One of these threads is yours. You'll see what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The same job or different job had left behind a zombie process. Any of old build task, svn checkout or git clone process related to this job, is still running or hung. Please check if any such process is running using ps command. If yes, terminate that process and this job will continue to run. This way you can fix this problem without restarting hudson.

Answer (score 1):

Have faced the same issue, based on my findings would be that SVN was asking password to be entered so, it stuck at that stage.  I have cleaned up the stored password in ~/.subversion directory. and then reentered the password. then it succeeded.